# is canceling animation frame always necessary

Tags: javascript

I know that I can manually cancel a `requestAnimationFrame` callback

```
function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  var progress = timestamp - start;
  element.style.left = Math.min(progress / 10, 200) + 'px';
  if (progress < 2000) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }
}

const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf)
```

The previous is mostly sample code from MDN docs.

My question is this:

Do I need to explicitly cancel `requestAnimationFrame` outside of wanting to cancel it early?

Specifically

```
if (progress < 2000) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

This stops recursively calling itself once progress is less than 2000.

Does that mean it's been cleared from the event loop?

Comment: note: the first code would never run `step` ... and no, there's no need to cancel a RAF unless you want to prevent a previously set RAF that has not already executed from executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not necessary

Because `requestAnimationFrame` only runs once, you should call it recursively after checking an exit condition (Exactly like in your example)

`cancelAnimationFrame` is useful when the animation can be stopped by an external event